# SWIG how to make a typedef function pointer in a struct callable from Python

Tags: python, c, function, struct, swig

**TL;DR**
Does anybody know how to instruct SWIG to treat these members of a C-struct as a function pointer and make it callable from Python?

**The full story** 
I have C structs which contain pointers to functions. The functions are all typedefed. I have a C function which will allocate memory for this C struct and which will set the function pointers to point to valid C functions.
My simplified header file looks like this

```
// simplified api.h
typedef void *handle_t;
typedef void sample_t;
typedef error_t comp_close_t(handle_t *h);
typedef error_t comp_process_t(handle_t h,
                               sample_t *in_ptr,
                               sample_t *out_ptr,
                               size_t *nr_samples);
typedef struct
{
    comp_close_t *close;
    comp_process_t *process;
} audio_comp_t;

// prototype for init
error_t comp_init(handle_t *h, int size);
```

And corresponding simplified source file:

```
// simplified api.c
static comp_close_t my_close;
static comp_process_t my_process;

audio_comp_t comp = {
    my_close,
    my_process
};

error_t comp_init(audio_comp_t **handle) {
    *handle = &comp;
    return 0;
}

error_t my_close(handle_t *h) {
    // stuff
    *h = NULL;
    return 0;
}

error_t my_process(handle_t h,
                   sample_t *in_ptr,
                   sample_t *out_ptr,
                   size_t *nr_samples) {
    audio_comp_t *c = (audio_comp_t*) h;
    // stuff 
    printf("doing something useful\n");
}
```

And the latest version of my interface file:

```
%module comp_wrapper
%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include "api.h"

// Take care of the double pointer in comp_init
%ignore comp_init;
%rename(comp_init) comp_init_overload;
%newobject comp_init;

%inline %{
audio_comp_t* comp_init_overload(int size) {
    audio_comp_t *result = NULL;
    error_t err = comp_init(&result, size);

    if (SSS_NO_ERROR == err) {
        ...
    }

    return result;
}
%}

// wrap the process call to verify the process_t * function pointer    
%inline %{
sss_error_t call_process(   audio_comp_t *h, 
                            sample_t *in, 
                            sample_t *out, 
                            size_t nr_samples)
{
    return h->process(h, in, out, &nr_samples);
}
%}
```

I want to use SWIG to create language bindings so that I can call these object-alike structures with minimal boiler plate code from Python. Ultimately I want to use this like:

```
h = comp_init(50)
h.process(h, input_data, output_data, block_size)
h.close(h)
```

However, SWIG treats these function pointers in these structs as Objects, so whenever I want to call them I get

```
>>> h = comp_init(50)
>>> h.api.process()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not callable
```

I can workaround it by means of something like the 'call_process' function which you can find in the interface file:

```
call_process(h, in, out, 32)
```

but it would require me to add an extra wrapper for all struct member functions, while this shouldn't be necessary since [the SWIG documentation states that function pointers are fully supported][1]

I assume I should write some code in the interface file so that SWIG knows that it's dealing with a function rather than a SwigPyObject

There is some information on how to deal with (python)callbacks, but none of it seems to work in this case specifically:
[SWIG call function pointers stored within struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791661/swig-call-function-pointers-stored-within-struct)

or without duplicating more or less all of the information from the header file into the interface file:
[Using SWIG with pointer to function in C struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583293/using-swig-with-pointer-to-function-in-c-struct)

and last but not least there seems to be a difference when you wrap a function pointer in a struct so solution 5 does not work: 
[How to wrap a c++ function which takes in a function pointer in python using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923696/how-to-wrap-a-c-function-which-takes-in-a-function-pointer-in-python-using-swi)

**Does anybody know how to instruct SWIG to treat these members of a C-struct as a function pointer and make it callable from Python?**

Comment: The example that you are self referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583293/using-swig-with-pointer-to-function-in-c-struct considers a struct with a function pointer member and shows how this can be called from Python. How is this different from what you are trying to do

Comment: The situation is the same. However the solution is not what I hoped it to be. 

Having to repeat every declaration of structure and function related to functions pointer in the interface file is not the best solution. 

In that case I might as well write the wrappers to call the code from python by hand. I specifically want to be able to tell SWIG to make function pointers callable.

Comment: SWIG is capable of so much more and you don't need to work on such a low level and use naked pointers and do casting. All functions can be wrapped and it can even generate a run-time, which can be used for querying stuff. My advice is to skip the `typedef`ed function prototypes and simply wrap the actual functions. The will be enclosed in a library. If you need initialization, use `attribute(constructor)` in *nix or in Windows `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH `

Comment: If you like, I have a small project here, which does a lot of swigging, http://github.com/JensMunkHansen/sofus

Comment: I'm currently thinking about solutions to this, but for now I've a quick point of clarification: Is it a mistake that `comp_process_t` takes a `handle_t`, but `comp_close_t` takes a `handle_t*`? Also are you willing to edit api.h a little, not changing the C API, but using some macros to make the SWIG interface simpler?

Comment: 1) no that's not a mistake, in the process call I use the pointer, in the close call I set it to NULL
2) Yes, I would be willing to adapt the C API a bit to accommodate SWIG, but preferably not too much and if possible #if // #ifdef blocks

Comment: Re: 1) - I'm not a fan of that personally - it doesn't do anything to other copies of `handle_t` which might be hanging around elsewhere in a program and in the case of SWIG bindings it only serves to clear a pointer which is in memory that itself should released shortly too. That said it's easy enough to make the destruction of the Python object automatically call this function exactly once if that's the semantics you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is if we claim to SWIG that the [function pointers are simply member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029809/168175) then the wrapper it will generate works quite nicely.

To demonstrate that in this instance we need to fix up a few errors in your sample code, so I ended up with api.h looking like this:

```c
// simplified api.h
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t api_error_t;

typedef void *handle_t;
typedef void sample_t;
typedef api_error_t comp_close_t(handle_t h);
typedef api_error_t comp_process_t(handle_t h,
                               sample_t *in_ptr,
                               sample_t *out_ptr,
                               size_t nr_samples);
typedef struct
{
    comp_close_t *close;
    comp_process_t *process;
} audio_comp_t;

// prototype for init
api_error_t comp_init(handle_t *new_h);
```

and api.c looking like this:

```
#include "api.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// simplified api.c
static comp_close_t my_close;
static comp_process_t my_process;

audio_comp_t comp = {
    my_close,
    my_process
};

api_error_t comp_init(handle_t *handle) {
    *handle = &comp;
    return 0;
}

api_error_t my_close(handle_t h) {
    (void)h; // stuff
    return 0;
}

api_error_t my_process(handle_t h,
                   sample_t *in_ptr,
                   sample_t *out_ptr,
                   size_t nr_samples) {
    audio_comp_t *c = (audio_comp_t*) h;
    (void)c;(void)in_ptr;(void)out_ptr;// stuff 
    printf("doing something useful\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With that in place we can write api.i as below:

```c
%module api

%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include <stdint.i>

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) handle_t *new_h (handle_t tmp) %{
    $1 = &tmp;
%}

%typemap(argout) handle_t *new_h %{
    if (!result) {
        $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(tmp$argnum, $descriptor(audio_comp_t *), 0 /*| SWIG_POINTER_OWN */);
    }
    else {
        // Do something to make the error a Python exception...
    }
%}

// From my earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029809/168175
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) handle_t self "$1=NULL;"
%typemap(check) handle_t self {
  $1 = arg1;
}

typedef struct {
  api_error_t close(handle_t self);
  api_error_t process(handle_t self,
                      sample_t *in_ptr,
                      sample_t *out_ptr,
                      size_t nr_samples);
} audio_comp_t;

%ignore audio_comp_t;
%include "api.h"
```

Here we've done a few things besides hiding the original structure and claiming it's full of member functions instead of member pointers:

1. Make SWIG [automatically pass the handle in as the 1st argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029809/168175) instead of requiring Python users to be excessively verbose. (In python it becomes `h.close()` instead of `h.close(h)`)
2. Use argout typemap to wrap the real `comp_init` function instead of just replacing it. That's purely a matter of preference I just added it to show how it could be used.

This lets my run the following Python:

```py
import api

h=api.comp_init()
print(h)
h.process(None, None, 0)
h.close()
```

---

We can do something that'll work quite nicely for both Python and C if you're willing to make some cosmetic changes to your API's header to facilitate things.

I introduced a macro into api.h, `MAKE_API_FUNC`, which wraps the typedef statements you had in it originally. When compiled with a C compiler it still produces the exact same results, however it lets us manipulate things better with SWIG.

So api.h now looks like this:

```c
// simplified api.h
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t api_error_t;

typedef void *handle_t;
typedef void sample_t;
#ifndef MAKE_API_FUNC
#define MAKE_API_FUNC(name, type, ...) typedef api_error_t comp_ ## name ## _t(__VA_ARGS__)
#endif

MAKE_API_FUNC(close, audio_comp_t, handle_t);
MAKE_API_FUNC(process, audio_comp_t, handle_t, sample_t *, sample_t *, size_t);

typedef struct
{
    comp_close_t *close;
    comp_process_t *process;
} audio_comp_t;

// prototype for init
api_error_t comp_init(handle_t *new_h);
```

So in api.i we now replace that macro, with another one, which claims to SWIG that the function pointer typedef is in fact a struct, with a specially provided `__call__` function. By creating this extra function we can proxy all our Python arguments automatically into a call to the real function pointer.

```c
%module api

%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include <stdint.i>

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653351
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

#define name_arg(num, type) arg_ ## num
#define param_arg(num, type) type name_arg(num, type)

#define FE_0(...)
#define FE_1(action,a1) action(0,a1)
#define FE_2(action,a1,a2) action(0,a1), action(1,a2)
#define FE_3(action,a1,a2,a3) action(0,a1), action(1,a2), action(2,a3)
#define FE_4(action,a1,a2,a3,a4) action(0,a1), action(1,a2), action(2,a3), action(3,a4)
#define FE_5(action,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) action(0,a1), action(1,a2), action(2,a3), action(3,a4), action(4,a5)

#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME
%define FOR_EACH(action,...)
  GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FE_5, FE_4, FE_3, FE_2, FE_1, FE_0)(action,__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

%define MAKE_API_FUNC(name, api_type, ...)
%nodefaultctor comp_ ## name ## _t;
%nodefaultdtor comp_ ## name ## _t;
typedef struct {
    %extend {
        api_error_t __call__(FOR_EACH(param_arg, __VA_ARGS__)) {
            return $self(FOR_EACH(name_arg, __VA_ARGS__));
        }
    }
} comp_ ## name ## _t;
// Workaround from: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/609
%rename("%s_fptr", "%$isvariable", "match$ismember"="1", "match$type"=xstr(comp_ ## name ## _t)) name;
%extend api_type {
    %pythoncode %{
        name = lambda self, *args: self.name ## _fptr(self, *args)
    %}
}
%enddef

%ignore comp_init;
%include "api.h"

%extend  audio_comp_t {
    audio_comp_t() {
        handle_t new_h = NULL;
        api_error_t err = comp_init(&new_h);
        if (err) {
            // throw or set Python error directly
        }
        return new_h;
    }

    ~audio_comp_t() {
        (void)$self;
        // Do whatever we need to cleanup properly here, could actually call close
    }
}
```

This is using the same [preprocessor mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11994395/168175) I used in [my answer on wrapping `std::function` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668302/168175), but applied to the function pointers of this problem. In addition I used [`%extend` to make a constructor/destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807099/168175) from the perspective of Python, which makes the API nicer to use. I'd probably use `%rename` too if this were real code.

With that said we can now use the following Python code:

```
import api

h=api.audio_comp_t()
print(h)
print(h.process)
h.process(None, None, 0)
```

See [SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Customization.html#Customization_exception) for a discussion on how to map the error codes onto exceptions nicely for Python too.

---

We can simplify this further, by removing the need to iterate over the arguments of the variadic macro, with one simple trick. If we change our api.h macro to take 3 arguments, the 3rd of which is all the function pointer's arguments like this:

```c
// simplified api.h
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t api_error_t;

typedef void *handle_t;
typedef void sample_t;
#ifndef MAKE_API_FUNC
#define MAKE_API_FUNC(name, type, args) typedef api_error_t comp_ ## name ## _t args
#endif

MAKE_API_FUNC(close, audio_comp_t, (handle_t self));
MAKE_API_FUNC(process, audio_comp_t, (handle_t self, sample_t *in_ptr, sample_t *out_ptr, size_t nr_samples));

typedef struct
{
    comp_close_t *close;
    comp_process_t *process;
} audio_comp_t;

// prototype for init
api_error_t comp_init(handle_t *new_h);
```

Then we can now change our SWIG interface to not provide a definition of the `__call__` function we added via `%extend`, and instead write a macro that directly makes the function pointer call we wanted:

```c
%module api

%{
#include "api.h"
%}

%include <stdint.i>

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2653351
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

%define MAKE_API_FUNC(name, api_type, arg_types)
%nodefaultctor comp_ ## name ## _t;
%nodefaultdtor comp_ ## name ## _t;
%{
#define comp_ ## name ## _t___call__(fptr, ...) fptr(__VA_ARGS__)
%}
typedef struct {
    %extend {
        api_error_t __call__ arg_types;
    }
} comp_ ## name ## _t;
// Workaround from: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/609
%rename("%s_fptr", "%$isvariable", "match$ismember"="1", "match$type"=xstr(comp_ ## name ## _t)) name;
%extend api_type {
    %pythoncode %{
        name = lambda self, *args: self.name ## _fptr(self, *args)
    %}
}
%enddef

%ignore comp_init;
%include "api.h"

%extend  audio_comp_t {
    audio_comp_t() {
        handle_t new_h = NULL;
        api_error_t err = comp_init(&new_h);
        if (err) {
            // throw or set Python error directly
        }
        return new_h;
    }

    ~audio_comp_t() {
        (void)$self;
        // Do whatever we need to cleanup properly here, could actually call close
    }
}
```

The tricky thing here was that the use of `typedef struct {...} name;` idiom made renaming or hiding the function pointers inside the struct harder. (That was only necessary however to keep the addition of the `handle_t` argument automatic however).

Comment: Great post! Thanks a lot for this!!

I've implemented the first part and will add the second part (which looks really interesting) to the backlog.